how to pass binary operators' functions to a function in Rust
use std::ops    


fn main () {
   struct BinOp {
     function:fn(~operator function arguments here~)
  }

  let binop = BinOp {
     function: ops::~operator function here~
  }
}

How to modify above code to:

make it possible to pass any binary operators' functions as a piece of data of an BinOp object?
pass binary operator function as a piece of data of binop variable?


It's not complicated at all, to take a generic function, you use generics and to pass a function you just pass the function:
use std::ops;
fn main() {
    struct Operator<T, U, Out> {
        function: fn(T, U) -> Out,
    }

    let operator: Operator<i32, i32, i32> = Operator {
        function: ops::Add::add,
    };
}


What do you want to achieve? because operators take different arguments, e.g.

Add::add(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
Neg::neg(self) -> Self::Output
i32::eq(&self, other: &i32) -> bool

Generic
If you just want binary operation, then you can just use generic as cafce25 pointed out.
simple generic with only <T>
struct Operator<T> {
    pub func: fn(T, T) -> T,
}

use std::ops::{Add, Mul, Neg};

fn main() {
    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::add };
    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::mul };
    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::wrapping_add };
    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::max };
    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::saturating_add };

    let _: Operator<f64> = Operator { func: f64::add };
    let _: Operator<f64> = Operator { func: f64::mul };
    let _: Operator<f64> = Operator { func: f64::atan2 };
    let _: Operator<f64> = Operator { func: f64::max };

    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::eq };
    //         error[E0308]: mismatched types
    //   --> ***\src/main.rs:20:45
    //    |
    // 19 |     let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::eq };
    //    |                                             ^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
    //    |
    //    = note: expected fn pointer `fn(_, _) -> i32`
    //                  found fn item `for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a _, &'b _) -> bool {<i32 as PartialEq>::eq}`
    let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::neg };
    //         error[E0308]: mismatched types
    //     --> fuck_around\src/main.rs:32:45
    //      |
    //   28 |     let _: Operator<i32> = Operator { func: i32::neg };
    //      |                                             ^^^^^^^^ incorrect number of function parameters
    //      |
    //      = note: expected fn pointer `fn(i32, i32) -> _`
    //                    found fn item `fn(i32) -> _ {<i32 as Neg>::neg}`
}

Different argument
you can use enum for different type of operation i.e. unary, binary, ternary...
use std::ops::{Add, Mul, Neg};

pub enum Operator<T>{
    Unary(fn (T) -> T),
    Binary(fn (T,T) -> T),
    Ternary(fn (T,T,T) -> T),
    Shifting(fn (T, u32) -> T),
    Compare(fn (&T, &T) -> bool),
    
    // If you want to include checked version
    // CheckedUnary(fn (T) -> Option<T>),
    // CheckedBinary(fn (T,T) -> Option<T>),
    // CheckedTernary(fn (T,T,T) -> Option<T>),
    // CheckedShifting(fn (T, u32) -> Option<T>),
}

fn main() {
    let _ : Operator<i32> = Operator::Unary(i32::neg);
    let _ : Operator<i32> = Operator::Binary(i32::add);
    let _ : Operator<i32> = Operator::Ternary(i32::clamp);
    let _ : Operator<i32> = Operator::Shifting(i32::wrapping_shl);
    let _ : Operator<i32> = Operator::Compare(i32::eq);

    let _ : Operator<f64> = Operator::Unary(f64::abs);
    let _ : Operator<f64> = Operator::Binary(f64::mul);
    let _ : Operator<f64> = Operator::Ternary(f64::mul_add);
    let _ : Operator<f64> = Operator::Compare(f64::ne);
}

